# How to add html img to page from javascript but not hardcode it in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I use `ajaxForm` to upload image. On success upload I add uploaded image to `div` on the page:

```
$("#ajaxUploadForm").ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            dataType: "json",
...
success: function (result) {
$("#imageList").prepend('<img src=' + result.message + '/>');
```

Now I was thinking that it is not smart to put this hardcoded `<img/>` tag in javascript code.
What is the best way to put image but not use `img` tag in prepend() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO that is the best way, there's no need to change anything. If you don't want to dynamically append/detach, you could have an existing `img` as a placeholder and just change its `src` attribute when you wanted to change it:

```
<img id="placeholder" src="initial/path" />

$("#placeholder").attr("src", result.message);
```

But since you're dealing with an image list, as your code suggested, I think your original solution is more appropriate for your case. If you ever decide to remove an image or sort the list or whatever, you can selected them using `$("imageList img")`.

*Edit:* OTOH if you have a very complex structure, that you want to code in HTML but also need to make dynamic copies of it, you can use [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) as an alternative:

```
<div id="model" style="display:none">complex markup goes here</div>

$("#model").clone().attr("id",anotherID).appendTo(target).show();
```

Comment: If you clone, you need to change the ids.

Answer (score 2):

i would not have any problem with that... unless you are worried about invalid url that could break the tag...

you could use simple javascript

```js
var img = new Image();
    img.src = result.message;

$("#imageList").prepend(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a template. For instance:

```
<div style="display:none">
  <!-- This div contains all your templates -->
  <img src="about:blank" class="classesYouNeed" id="uploadSuccess">
</div>
```

and then use javascript:

```
$("#ajaxUploadForm").ajaxForm({
  iframe: true,
  dataType: "json",
  ...
  success: function (result) {
    var img = $('#uploadSuccess')
      .clone()
      .attr('id', somethingElse)
      .attr('src', result.message)

    $("#imageList").prepend(img);
  })
})
```

There are jQuery templating frameworks out there that will make this much easier.